# local notification repeatinterval with a specific minute of the hour

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.5, uilocalnotification, repeatingalarm

I'm trying here to repeat a local notification for every hour. so I tried this sample code:

```
UILocalNotification *reminderNote = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    reminderNote.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60 * 60];
    reminderNote.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
    reminderNote.alertBody = @"some text";
    reminderNote.alertAction = @"View";
    reminderNote.soundName = @"sound.aif";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:reminderNote];
```

and it worked fine. But when I try to repeat it at a specific minute of the hour, say every hour sharp, or every hour and 6 mins. I just couldn't figure out a way to do that! I tried to change SinceNow to anything else but it's not working!

Is there a way change it? or any other sample code that I should work on?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Related post here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820428/uilocalnotification-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the repeat interval between the first and the second reminder repetition is different from the interval for the rest, you need to define a **new** local notification with the correct fire date, e.g. 6 minutes after the hour. Then set the repeat interval to the `NSHourCalendarUnit`.

You can specify the interval with the usual pattern with `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents`. This is well documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thank you. But it's actually all the intervals are the same for now. So for example, I want the notification to fire 7 minutes after the hour... Now when I tried the code provided above. It actually started counting from the minute the app became active. Not from a specified minute. As it stated SinceNow.. "reminderNote.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60 * 60];"

Comment: Well, don't use "sinceNow". Use the date computed with the correct minute!

Comment: I did what you said but it's still not working. I tried to show you my work here but there isn't enough space so I'll post the new code in a new question. Thanks a lot for your notes.

Comment: You *can* post more code in the question. I would be happy to look at it.

Comment: can you please check out my new question.. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247784/whats-wrong-with-my-notification-code)

Answer (score 1):

```
reminderNote.repeatInterval = NSHourCalendarUnit;
```

Comment: but how to specify the minute?

Comment: in minutes.....
yourNotificationObject.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
and in seconds
yourNotificationObject.repeatInterval = NSSecondCalendarUnit;

Comment: question is not answered correctly. @P.J your code will repeat every hour but here requirement is of every hour and 6 minutes.

Comment: @DheerajGupta My role is just editor here, nothing more. If you want answer to this question, it has already been answered in previous answer