# What's Wrong with my notification code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, repeatingalarm

Note: there is an update below.

I've asked in the previous question about specifying a minute for an hourly repeat interval.
However, I had two answers asking me to try the date component, and I did. Here it is:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] ;
NSDateComponents *componentsForReferenceDate = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[componentsForReferenceDate setHour:hour];
[componentsForReferenceDate setMinute:0];
[componentsForReferenceDate setSecond:0];

 NSDate *fireDateOfNotification = [calendar dateFromComponents: componentsForReferenceDate];
 // Create the notification
 UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init] ;

 notification.fireDate = fireDateOfNotification;
 notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone] ;
 notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"You are missed!"] ;
 notification.alertAction = @"View";
 notification.userInfo= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some information"] forKey:@"information"];
 notification.repeatInterval= NSHourCalendarUnit ;
 notification.soundName = @"Appnotifisound.wav";
 notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification] ;
```

The code seems to me right and it should work as I've been told it should fire a notification at the beginning of every hour. However, it does not! The code is complete, I have set the properties and synthesize it right even the NSCalendar is there. It builds and runs flawlessly, However, it never fires a notification for every hour on my simulator!? I just couldn't get what seems to be wrong. Please let me know if you need more information or copy the other parts of the code to help me finding what's missing. Thank you.

Update: Here is how I coded the Hour if it might be the problem..

```
NSCalendar *calendar1 = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar1 components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
hour = [components hour];
min =[components minute];
sec =[components second];
NSLog(@"hour is %i",hour);

NSLog(@"min is %i",min);

NSLog(@"sec is %i",sec);
 if (hour < 24) {
     hour=hour+1;
     } else {
         hour=0;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something that stumped me: you won't see the notification while the app is in the foreground. You need to hit the home button on the simulator to put the app into the background or else, to see something while the app is active, implement the app delegate protocol method: `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification` in your app and make that method display something.

Comment: could you elaborate on what you would implement in that method in order to see the notification locally?

Comment: Well that's up to you, it could be anything, create a UIAlertView if the notification needs to alert the user to something... ? You'll also need to play the sound if you want the user to hear something.

Comment: But simply implementing that method with an empty method body, would you see the notification itself, as a banner, etc...?

Comment: No, nothing while the application is active. You have to do all the work :) Local notifications are designed to alert user only if the app is in the background.

Comment: Apple has decent document about it: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1

Comment: I actually hit the home button every time I run it on the simulator and it's still not working. Also, in order to test it running a the head of every hour, I change my computer's time time Hr:59:00

Comment: I had it alerting every minute while testing, and it worked in all scenarios: App in background, locked home screen, while app in fore ground (with delegate method and UIAlertView). Hardcode the hour value and change the frequency to  `NSMinuteCalendarUnit` and see if you can make it display

Comment: @AndrewTetlaw you mean like this? NSCalendar *calendar1 = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar1 components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
hour = [components hour];
min =[components minute];
sec =[components second];
NSLog(@"hour is %i",hour);

NSLog(@"min is %i",min);

NSLog(@"sec is %i",sec);
 if (hour < 24) {
     hour=hour+1;
     } else {
         hour=0;

Comment: You are brilliant! I did change it to NSMinuteCalendarUnit and found it firing a the minute and 52 seconds instead of at beginning of the Minute!! So it has to be the hour hardcoding that has something missing, right? were you able to figure it out?

Comment: I didn't, but I can't help thinking that your condition `hour < 24` will allow the hour to reach `24`.

Comment: I had it less than 24 so it return to 0 again and starts from there. Will you show me, how would you code the hour? so it starts once it turns to the next hour.

Comment: Except if hour = 23, then it'll execute hour = hour + 1 and now it's 24

Comment: Ok thanks, but no idea why is it firing twice at min: 52? while asking for once at min:0?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me when i copy this code, except i don't set your sound and you have not shown how you set 'hour' so i hard coded it.  Here is the output.

> 2013-01-09 17:57:17.968 TestStackOverflow[3322:11303] fireDate =
>   0001-01-01 06:17:32 +0000 2013-01-09 17:57:17.993
>   TestStackOverflow[3322:11303] +++scheduledLocalNotifications (
>       "{fire date = Monday, January 1, 1, 1:00:00 AM GMT-05:17:32, time zone = America/Toronto
>   (EST) offset -18000, repeat interval = NSHourCalendarUnit, repeat
>   count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date =
>   Wednesday, January 9, 2013, 6:17:32 PM Eastern Standard Time, user
>   info = {\n    information = \"Some information\";\n}}"

Comment: Here is how I set the hour in AppDelegat.h '@property (readwrite,nonatomic) NSInteger hour;' it's still not working! Could you please show me your hour code. and what might be the problem I'm facing? Also to test it out, I actually change my computer to Hr:59:00 every time so I see if it's firing the notification or not

Comment: Sorry here is how I coded the Hour... NSCalendar *calendar1 = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar1 components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    hour = [components hour];
    min =[components minute];
    sec =[components second];
    NSLog(@"hour is %i",hour);
    
    NSLog(@"min is %i",min);
    
    NSLog(@"sec is %i",sec);
     if (hour < 24) {
         hour=hour+1;
         } else {
             hour=0;